# Use autocomplete variables from first column of a CSV file

Tags: auto-complete-mode, csv

I have used conventional auto complete feature in emacs and I think I understand how it works.

I have a new requirement, where the variables to be used in a particular program (not conventional programming like C/C++/Python - but some text based file) would be listed in the first column of the CSV file. All those variables will start with a ":"(semicolon).

I want emacs to use auto complete the conventional way (i.e, auto complete the variables used in the current file) *plus fetch these variables from the first column of the CSV file.*

I do not know if this such a thing has got a name or not for this. Also, I have no idea on how I could point the CSV file to use from the current file.

Comment: For those of you who feel, this is less of a question and more like a discussion, I have posted the same question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/dsqykz/use_autocomplete_variables_from_first_column_of_a/). Will catch up with you guys there, if this question gets closed here

Comment: Maybe that way: Check for value of completion-at-point-functions. Make sure, the csv-file gets opened and advice completions-at-point-function calling dabbrev-expand.